# array search & count - scala

Tags: arrays, algorithm, scala

I am trying to find the # of elements in a wrapped array. Below are the scenarios.

Array need not be sorted.

It works with a for loop and it is highly inefficient. Is there a better approach?

[image]

The dates are in wrapped array (unsorted) - the user will specify the start and end dates and number of elements between them has to be counted.

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date

def convertStringToDate(s: String): Date = {
  val DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd"
  val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT)
  dateFormat.parse(s)
}

val startDate = convertStringToDate("2016-02-01")
val endDate = convertStringToDate("2020-03-01")

val journeyDates = Array("2019-03-01", "2016-07-23", "2018-03-17", "2018-11-31", "2016-01-31").map(
  x => convertStringToDate(x)
)

def filterDates(
    datesArray: Array[java.util.Date],
    startDate: java.util.Date,
    endDate: java.util.Date
): Array[java.util.Date] = {
  datesArray.filter(date => date.after(startDate) && date.before(endDate))
}

val filteredDates = filterDates(journeyDates,startDate,endDate)
```

The code is not very efficient - and looking to optimize for performance.

Comment: Hi @rakesh, can you please share a sample of data and eventually a code snippet of what you already tried so we can help ?

Comment: thanks - edited with the code & sample data

Comment: Thank you @rakesh. Can you also tell us which parts can't be changed ? you're working with the Date datataype. Is that a mandatory input datatype or you're using it for comparison purpose ?

Comment: The core filtering algorithm cannot be improved. You still need to look at every element and select the ones that match the criteria. Maybe the performance improves if you use a Scala List instead of Array for holding your data.

Comment: Also try using newer Java Date API and avoid `java.util.Date`. That also can improve performance. Use [LocalDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) as it is the recommended way for Java 8 and above.

Comment: thanks @baitmbarek - yes we have a date column and we need to use it for comparison.